# Show ACF to front end custom post

Tags: custom-post-types

I have the *Newspaper* theme, installed custom post plugin and ACF plugin pro with ACF plugin to copypaste code somewhere.

Setting up both in backend was easy but the last part I do not understand.
Where (which file, which line) must I paste the PHP code to show up in custom post type?

Looking through all files I did not find any new ones named as my custom post type, same results with notepad++ searching inside all files also.
On ACF forum answer cant be found as devs are not giving support to the usage of ACF on custom post types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get familiar with [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) to understand in which template WordPress will display your custom post type. If you have sample custom post type named `event` with title `Lorem ipsum`, WordPress will watch for this files in that order in your theme to display such a custom post type:

- `single-$post_type-$slug.php` for our case it will be
  `single-event-lorem-ipsum.php`
- `single-$post_type.php` for our case it will be `single-event.php`
- `single.php`
- `singluar.php`
- `index.php`

If WordPress will not find first of the file from list it will be looking for second and so on.

Most of the themes has `single.php` file and probably your custom post type will be displayed by this template. Good practice would be to create separate template file for custom post type, probably you want to display it display differently than others post, named `single-event.php`. For start I would copy `single.php` content, paste it to `single-event.php` file and add there your ACF code.

Comment: Name of the custom post type is event. i have tried with single-event.php and with event.php. I am not sure where to paste code ? Original single.php has some php code inside and finishes with get_footer. I added code 3 lines before and tried at beggining but no luck.

Comment: `event.php` is wrong you should try with `single-event.php` or `single.php`. Where to paste the code? If ACF fields have custom values for each event you should place code inside loop. Somewhere between `while ( $query->have_posts() ):` and `endwhile;`. If editing php files is overwhelming for you you can try display ACF fields with shortcodes placed in your content e.g. `[acf field="name"]` where `name` is your field name. I do not have enough information to help you more, what theme you are using?

Comment: Thx motivast. I have tried with default single.php and single-event.php. Using Newspaper theme from CodeCanyon. Did not find lines you mention where i should add php code. I searched whole theme folder with notepad++ for those lines but no luck. Maybe its important, custom post type is made with plugin Custom Post Type UI 1.5.6. and PostTypeSlug is named event. I will also try [acf field="name"] on single.php.

Comment: Tried [acf field="name"], no luck. Its proly becouse i am not sure where to add this in single.php.

Comment: I have this Newspaper theme https://themeforest.net/item/newspaper/5489609. I don't know if you have it to. If yes I have opened `loop-single.php` file and paste `<?php the_field('test'); ?>` code after `<?php echo $td_mod_single->get_content();?>`. My value from this field showed after post content and banner.

Comment: Thx a lot motivast. It took some time but i figured it out. I also managed to get field names to display. Only things left is how to make it show above banner ? Yep, im using same theme.

Comment: To display it before banner you have to open `td_module_single_base.php` file located in `Newspaper/includes/wp_booster/td_module_single_base.php`, search for `get_content` method and paste your ACF code after `$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);` line like that `$content .= get_field('test');`. Take a note I'm now using `get_field` function instead of `the_field` and `.=` notation.

Comment: All good, but something is different now. Cant add line field name, line break(i get error with br, which worked in previous file, and get_field will not show oembed ?